# Angular Parser doesn't trigger second time

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom directive, which takes input of type text, formats the input and doesn't allow user to type alphabets (numbers only).The parser works fine with a minor bug. If i  try to enter an alphabet first time it doesn't allow me which is right, but second time it does allow me to type and it doesn't trigger parser function. Can some one tell me where is my mistake?

```
ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
        });
 ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
            elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
            return plainNumber;
        });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t96fkuu7/5/.

Answer (score 1):

The focus of formatting a model's DOM value as a user inputs text is on the ngModelController's `$parsers`, that's the pipeline the viewValue will pass through when input is changed through the DOM.

To do this you will need to manually set the `$viewValue` property on the model controller and call `$render` to update the DOM.

```
// in your directive's link function
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
  var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');

  ctrl.$viewValue = $filter('number')(plainNumber);
  ctrl.$render();

  // return the modelValue
  return plainNumber
}
```

Here's an updated working example: https://jsfiddle.net/17k7em04/

Note you shouldn't call `$setViewValue` from within `$parsers`, it will cause an infinite loop in earlier versions of angular because it calls the $parsers functions.

Answer (score 0):

In your parser, do not access the element directly - let ngModelController do the work for you!

So instead of

```
elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
```

Check if something changed and tell ngModelController to get going...

```
if (plainNumber != viewValue) {
   ctrl.$setViewValue(plainNumber);
   ctrl.$render();
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion. I can use ngModelController, but it has array with one element in it if i need to access $setViewValue I have use ngModelController[0], which seems weird to me. Can you tell any reason why I have array?

Comment: Is the jsfiddle your real code? If not - post your real code... Because I tried it with your Fiddle, it definitely works: see https://jsfiddle.net/t96fkuu7/9/

Comment: What do you mean by my real code? The fiddle works fine, but if you try the scenario I mentioned you can reproduce the bug.

Comment: Did you try the Fiddle I linked in _my comment_?

Comment: Didn't see it, sorry about that. I will try that. Thank you very much